# Query for rows within a date range that also have a specified substring

Tags: mysql, sql, date, wildcard

I'm trying to query a MySQL database and return all records within a given date range and which also contain the substring 'bank' in the content column.

The format of the 'time' field I refer to is `mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss`.

Here's the statement I've come up with but MySQL Workbench is giving me issues:

```
SELECT * 
FROM blogs 
WHERE ((‘time’ BETWEEN “04/01/2011 00:00:00” AND “04/15/2011 23:59:59”) 
   AND (‘content’ LIKE ‘%bank%’))
```

Comment: if you do a select without the time limitation, what raw data do you get returned?  Looking at the MySQL documentation for date and time types, there is no format for mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss (from https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-types.html).

Comment: Dates and times adhere to a specific format in sql. This is not it. And don't use Word to format queries!

Comment: Following the above comments, can we assume that `time` column is a `VARCHAR()` type?

Comment: OP, are you still working to figure this one out?

Comment: @McAdam331 I was able to get it to work, it was an issue with the double quotes. Thanks all for the help!

Answer (score 2):

How about trying this:

```
SELECT * 
    FROM blogs 
    WHERE `time` BETWEEN '2011-04-01 00:00:00' AND '2011-04-15 23:59:59' 
        AND `content` LIKE '%bank%';
```

This works if your `time` field is in fact a timestamp.  If `time` is not a timestamp then you will have to go with something like the answer from **McAdam331** but I'm hoping your database is using the correct types for the kind of data you are asking it to store.

single **'** or double **"** quotes around values and ticks ` around field names.  I also changed the date format to yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss and eliminated some unnecessary parentheses.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/730bd/1/0

It would be helpful if you posted the structure of the table when posting questions like this so we can be sure to give the right answer.

Comment: Thanks for the shout out ;P I like this answer, and to be honest it comes down to whether OP is using timestamp or strings. If they are using timestamp, I suspect it's either the use of double quotes that are causing the problem, or that they are using the wrong format of strings for comparison, both of which you covered well.

Answer (score 1):

It isn't a good idea to store dates like that in MySQL. The DBMS has [Date and Time Types](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-types.html) you can use to store that information.

If changing the database isn't an option, you can convert a string to a date object using the [STR_TO_DATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function%5Fstr-to-date) function, which takes in a date string and the format that it is in already and returns a date.

MySQL stores dates in the 'YYYY-MM-DD' format, so to get that format you can try something like this:

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE('04/01/2011', '%m/%d/%Y');
```

Which will return a date object for that day. **Note the capital Y.**

Then it becomes much easier to query between dates, like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM myTable
WHERE STR_TO_DATE(dateString, '%m/%d/%Y %H:%i:%s') BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE('04/01/2011 00:00:00', '%m/%d/%Y %H:%i:%s') AND STR_TO_DATE('04/15/2011 23:59:59', '%m/%d/%Y %H:%i:%s')
      AND content LIKE '%bank%';
```

Here is an [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8a44f/1) example, and here is a [link](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_date_format.asp) that has the formatting characters you need.